SVM tuning process: Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
I don't understand the output of the tuning process of SVM model.
Here is my code.
basic_recipe <-
  recipe(target ~ 
           loan_type + New_versus_Repeat + 
           Total_Amount + Total_Amount_to_Repay +
           disbursement_date + due_date + duration +
           Amount_Funded_By_Lender + Lender_portion_Funded + Lender_portion_to_be_repaid, 
         data = train) |>
  step_string2factor(loan_type, levels = all_loan_type) |>
  step_string2factor(New_versus_Repeat, levels = all_new_versus_repeat) |>
  step_other(loan_type, threshold = 0.1 / 100) |>
  step_date(all_date()) |>
  step_log(duration, Total_Amount, Total_Amount_to_Repay, Amount_Funded_By_Lender, Lender_portion_to_be_repaid, base = 10, offset = 0.001) |>
  step_normalize(Total_Amount, Total_Amount_to_Repay, Amount_Funded_By_Lender, Lender_portion_to_be_repaid, Lender_portion_to_be_repaid, na_rm = TRUE) |>
  step_cut(duration, breaks = ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$x) |>
  step_dummy(loan_type, New_versus_Repeat, duration, one_hot = TRUE)

svm_model <-
  svm_rbf(mode = "classification", cost = tune(), rbf_sigma = tune()) |>
  set_engine("kernlab")

control_gd <- control_grid(
  verbose = TRUE,
  save_pred = FALSE,
  parallel_over = "everything"
)

set.seed(1)

svm_wf <-
  workflow() |>
  add_model(svm_model) |>
  add_recipe(basic_recipe)

svm_grid <-
  grid_regular(
    cost(),
    rbf_sigma(),
    levels = c(3, 3)
  )

svm_tune <- 
  svm_wf |>
  tune_grid(
    resamples = folds,
    grid = svm_grid,
    metrics = metrics,
    control = control_gd
  )

Here is the output on the first resample Resample01
Resample01: preprocessor 1/1
✓ Resample01: preprocessor 1/1
i Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/9
! Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/9: Variable(s) `' constant. Cannot scale data.
✓ Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/9
i Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/9 (extracts)
i Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/9 (predictions)
x Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/9 (predictions):
  Error in `$<-`:
  ! Assigned data `orig_rows` must be compatible with existing data.
  ✖ Existing data has 6456 rows.
  ✖ Assigned data has 6492 rows.
  ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
  Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
  ! Can't recycle input of size 6492 to size 6456.
i Resample01: preprocessor 1/1
✓ Resample01: preprocessor 1/1
i Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/9
! Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/9: Variable(s) `' constant. Cannot scale data.
✓ Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/9
i Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/9 (extracts)
i Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/9 (predictions)
x Resample01: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/9 (predictions):
  Error in `$<-`:
  ! Assigned data `orig_rows` must be compatible with existing data.
  ✖ Existing data has 6456 rows.
  ✖ Assigned data has 6492 rows.
  ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
  Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
  ! Can't recycle input of size 6492 to size 6456.


I don't understand the errors.
Can anyone help me to understand it? Did I do something wrong?
